# couldn't download the Magento PHP 5.4 support Community Edition Patches

Tags: magento

I went to this Mangento file download page

http://www.magentocommerce.com/download?icid=BLOG_php54_downloadpage

and selected the option "Magento-CE-v1.7.0.0-1.7.0.2" and clicked the orange download button. There is no files downloaded to my computer at all. But After 2 seconds, I was redirected to this page.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/index.php/getmagento/ce_patches/PATCH_SUPEE-2629_EE_1.12.0.0_v1.sh

Can anyone tell me how to download the Magento PHP 5.4 patches file?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you actually did download it, it's all in the saving...

When the Magento website redirects to the page, go to your file menu (Fire Fox, Chrome -> Save Page As) and save the file. It should preserve the proper .sh file name in the dialog prompt file name. This saved file is your patch.

This patch is just a *nix shell script and since your browser sees it as plain text, it displays it instead of trying to download it.

Don't use IE to download the patch, as this Microsoft beauty of semi-compliance doesn't properly handle Unix line endings (LF) so you get a long concatenated string because the line ending isn't DOS-centric CR-LF